# Jax WS - wsgen throwing ModelerException: Web service endpoint could not be found

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, endpoints

This is a common problem. But looks like my classes and interface are annotated correctly. Please let me know if I am overlooking at something. Thanks in advance. I searched a lot in internet but nothing helping me out.

Exception details:

```
C:\Indu\workspaceWS\CalculatorWS>wsgen -s src -verbose -d bin -cp bin com.indu.w
s.services.CalcServiceImpl

warning: The apt tool and its associated API are planned to be
removed in the next major JDK release.  These features have been
superseded by javac and the standardized annotation processing API,
javax.annotation.processing and javax.lang.model.  Users are
recommended to migrate to the annotation processing features of
javac; see the javac man page for more information.
Note:   ap round: 1
Problem encountered during annotation processing;
see stacktrace below for more information.
com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.ModelerException: [failed to localiz
e] A web service endpoint could not be found()
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAP.o
nError(WebServiceAP.java:219)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAP.b
uildModel(WebServiceAP.java:326)
        at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAP.p
rocess(WebServiceAP.java:260)
```

My Code:
Implementation Class:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "CalculatorService", endpointInterface = 
"com.indu.ws.services.CalcIntService", 
targetNamespace="http://com/indu/ws/services/",
portName="CalcIntServicePortType")
public class CalcServiceImpl implements CalcIntService {
```

Interface:

```
@WebService(name = "CalcIntServicePortType", targetNamespace = 
"http://com/indu/ws/services/", 
 wsdlLocation="WEB-INF/wsdl/CalculatorWS.wsdl")
public interface CalcIntService {
@WebMethod
public int doService(Calculator c);
    }
```